# What do I need to change in toggle function to show 1 element at a time rather than show all elements?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building a dog breed info application and when I click on the breed name I want to show the info for that breed only. Currently, the toggle function does show the dog breed info when the breed name is clicked but it shows the info for all breeds rather than just the breed clicked.

I think the problem is that I'm not calling the object id correctly but I can't figure out where the id needs to be called. What am I missing? Thanks!

```
class Dog extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            dogInfo: [
                {
                    id: 1,
                    key: 'dogBreed',
                    breedName: 'Tibetan Mastiff',
                    class: 'Working',
                    colors: ['Black', 'Black & Tan', 'Blue Gray', 'Blue Gray & Tan', 'Brown', 'Brown & Tan', 'Red Gold', 'Red Gold Sable'],
                    image: tibetanMastiff,
                    alt: 'Black and Tan Tibetan Mastiff'
                },
                {
                    id: 2,
                    key: 'dogBreed',
                    breedName: 'Great Dane',
                    class: 'Working',
                    colors: ['Black', 'Black & White', 'Blue', 'Brindle', 'Fawn', 'Harlequin', 'Mantle', 'Merle', 'White'],
                    image: greatDane,
                    alt: 'Merle Great Dane'
                },
                {
                    id: 3,
                    key: 'dogBreed',
                    breedName: 'Cavalier King Charles Spaniel',
                    class: 'Toy',
                    colors: ['Blenheim', 'Black & Tan', 'Tri-Color', 'Ruby'],
                    image: cavalier,
                    alt: 'Tri-Color Cavalier King Charles Spaniel'
                },
                {
                    id: 4,
                    key: 'dogBreed',
                    breedName: 'Italian Greyhound',
                    class: 'Toy',
                    colors: ['Black', 'Blue', 'Blue Fawn', 'Cream', 'Fawn', 'Red', 'Red Fawn', 'Sable', 'Seal'],
                    image: italianGrayhound,
                    alt: 'Fawn Italian Grayhound'

                }
            ]
        }
    }

    toggleSelected(id, key){
        let temp = this.state[key]
        temp[id].selected = !temp[id].selected
        this.setState({
            [key]: temp
        })
    }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
                <div className='wrapper'>
                    <DogList 
                        title='Choose Dog Breed'
                        breedInfo={this.state.dogInfo}
                        toggleItem={this.toggleSelected}
                    />
                </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Dog;


class DogList extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
       listOpen: false,
       headerTitle: this.props.title
    }
   }

   toggleList(){
    this.setState(prevState => ({
       listOpen: !prevState.listOpen
    }))
   }

   render(){
    const{breedInfo} = this.props
    const{listOpen, headerTitle} = this.state

    return(
       <div>
          <div >{headerTitle}</div>
          {<ul onClick={() => this.toggleList()}>
        {breedInfo.map((dog) => (
        <li key={dog.id} >{dog.breedName}               
        {listOpen && <ul onClick={() => this.toggleList()}>
           <img src={dog.image}/>
           <li key={dog.id} >{dog.colors.map((color) => (                        
                      <ul>                           
                         <li>{color}</li>                
                      </ul>
           ))}</li>
        </ul>}
        </li>
            ))}
          </ul>}
       </div>
    )
   }
}

export default DogList;
```

Comment: are you expecting a solution like this https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-uqn9gz ?

Comment: @smallDisgruntledDog. I just wrote you an answer that should explain what's wrong with your current code and give you a couple of ways to fix it :). Let me know if you have any questions. If you have found an answer to your question, please mark it as the answer so others will be able to reference it in the future.

Comment: @ChristopherNgo. Thanks, it worked perfectly! I ended up using option 2. I had wanted to make a separate component like DogBreed, but just confused myself more when I attempted it previously. Really appreciate you taking the time to make the codesandboxes. Helped clarify my understanding of the code structure.

Comment: @smallDisgruntledDog you're very welcome! I'm glad this helped you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello smallDisgruntledDog, great name by the way. Taking a look at your code, there are a variety of ways to accomplish what you're looking for. As currently constructed, it looks like you are trying to make use of your `toggleList()`function to display one dog-breed at a time. However, the listOpen value is shared across all of your dogs, so it ends up opening all lists. There is no unique value being passed to determine which dog was selected.

I have 2 ways for you to solve this.

Option 1) Add an extra state value in your DogList component called selectedDog. Update your toggleList function to take in a dog breed value, which we will use to update the selectedDog state. Now in order to display a dog list, both listOpen has to be true and the selectedDog must match dog.breedName:

```
import React from "react";
class DogList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      listOpen: false,
      headerTitle: this.props.title,
      selectedDog: null
    };
  }

  toggleList(dogBreed) {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      listOpen: !prevState.listOpen,
      selectedDog: dogBreed
    }));
  }

  render() {
    const { breedInfo } = this.props;
    const { listOpen, headerTitle, selectedDog } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <div>{headerTitle}</div>
        {
          <ul>
            {breedInfo.map(dog => (
              <li key={dog.id} onClick={() => this.toggleList(dog.breedName)}>
                {dog.breedName}
                {listOpen && selectedDog === dog.breedName && (
                  <ul>
                    <img src={dog.image} />
                    <li key={dog.id}>
                      {dog.colors.map(color => (
                        <ul>
                          <li>{color}</li>
                        </ul>
                      ))}
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                )}
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default DogList;
```

Option 2) Separate each Dog into a different component. I'm going to display this using a component called DogBreed. There are many benefits to doing this including writing cleaner code, giving each dog their own state and giving us more control over each dog.

DogBreed component:

```
import React from "react";

class DogBreed extends React.Component {
  state = {
    show: false
  };

  handleClick = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      return {
        show: !prevState.show
      };
    });
  };
  render() {
    const { show } = this.state;
    return (
      <li onClick={this.handleClick}>
        {this.props.breedName}
        {show ? (
          <ul>
            <img src={this.props.image} />
            <li>
              {this.props.colors.map(color => (
                <ul>
                  <li>{color}</li>
                </ul>
              ))}
            </li>
          </ul>
        ) : null}
      </li>
    );
  }
}

export default DogBreed;
```

Updated DogList component:

```
import React from "react";
import DogBreed from "./DogBreed";

class DogList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      headerTitle: this.props.title
    };
  }

  toggleList() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      listOpen: !prevState.listOpen
    }));
  }

  render() {
    const { breedInfo } = this.props;
    const { headerTitle } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <div>{headerTitle}</div>
        {
          <ul>
            {breedInfo.map(dog => (
              <DogBreed
                breedName={dog.breedName}
                colors={dog.colors}
                image={dog.image}
              />
            ))}
          </ul>
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default DogList;
```

Let me know if you have any questions. For reference, here are the codesandboxes for both options:

Option 1: https://codesandbox.io/s/1x82qq82j

Option 2: https://codesandbox.io/s/v3062w69v0